# Zimbardo’s Stanford prison experiment with women

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, methodology

In the (in)famous experiment by psychologist Zimbardo at Stanford, also called the [Stanford Prison Experiment](https://www.prisonexp.org/), my understanding is that only males were selected. Is there any other analogous experiment with women only, or women and men, and what was their result?

Comment: Note that Stanford Prison was not an experiment, but a role-play and simulation, or demo, or at best, a pilot.  Thus we do not have a "result" for a men-only experiment either.  There have been partial replications by [Reicher & Haslam (2006)](https://doi.org/10.1348/014466605X48998) and [Lovibond, Mithiran, & Adams (1979)](https://doi.org/10.1080/00050067908254355) but both recruited only men.